File Upload Issue on Github for selenium with Java script
I am trying to automate file upload using Selenium with Java in GitHub workflows. The script works perfectly on my local machine, but I encounter issues when running it on GitHub. I suspect it might be related to file permissions or the configuration of the GitHub runner (macOS).
Here are the steps I have taken so far:
Verified the file paths and permissions.
Adjusted the YAML file configurations to ensure proper setup.
Ensured the runner has the necessary permissions and environment setup.
Despite these efforts, the file upload fails in the GitHub workflow environment. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide insights on how to resolve this?
